# Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1 on Validation Rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule, error

I've been getting error on validating my formula to check if an option list has a certain value, and if any of the field has been changed, and I'm getting the error that it only received 1 parameter, I really lost there

```
IF(
   AND(
      ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Em Aprovação'), 
      OR(
         ISCHANGED(OrderNumber),
         ISCHANGED(Solicitante__c),
         ISCHANGED(MargemLiquida__c),
         ISCHANGED(TotalAmount),
         ISCHANGED(operacao__c),
         ISCHANGED(MargemBruta__c),
         ISCHANGED(CurrencyIsoCode),
         ISCHANGED(QuantidadeFaturadaTotal__c),
         ISCHANGED(Produto_do_pedido__c),
         ISCHANGED(EffectiveDate),
         ISCHANGED(ContaEntrega__c),
         ISCHANGED(RemessaIndustrializacao__c),
         ISCHANGED(FaturaParcial__c),
         ISCHANGED(PedidoCaronaBottega__c),
         ISCHANGED(SomatorioMargemBruta__c),
         ISCHANGED(SomatorioMargemLiquida__c),
         ISCHANGED(ContaFaturamento__c),
         ISCHANGED(ContaFaturamento__c),
         ISCHANGED(Aceita2Retalho__c),
         ISCHANGED(UnidadeMedida__c),
         ISCHANGED(PedidoCortesia__c),
         ISCHANGED(QuantidadeProdutos__c),
         ISCHANGED(PedidoCompra__c)
      ),
      True, 
      False
   )
),
```

Comment: I have formatted your formula according to best practice, which makes it easier to read and spot issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to get lost in a sea of parenthesis. To help avoid that, the recommendation is that you treat formulas like code. One statement per line, and indent an additional level with each open parenthesis.

Doing so makes the issue here easy to spot. You've included the `true, false`) bit inside of your `AND()` instead of having it be the second and third parameters for the `IF()` function. You also have an extra comma at the end.

That said, you don't need the `IF()` at all here. `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can *always* be reduced to simply `<condition>`. Likewise, `IF(<condition>, false, true)` can *always* be reduced to simply `NOT(<condition>)`

Your formula here just needs to be

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Em Aprovação'), 
    OR(
      <your collection of field change checks here>
    )
)
```

Comment: Alternatively, this gives me the feeling that you're pretty much trying to recreate an [Approval Process](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_my_pending.htm&language=en_USF&type=5)